# How to prevent doubleclick to zoom in on mobile with alpinejs

Tags: alpine.js

What I've tried is

```
@click="playInstance()"
```

and

```
@click.prevent="playInstance()"
```

with a simple

```
playInstance() {
      audioObj.play();
},
```

When I add prevent, stops the zooming but also the click doesn't start the audio.

What I want is the multi tapping to execute the play without zooming my elements because of double tapping.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem was not in AlpineJS part,

I made it work on mobiles (and desktops) with:

```
@touchstart.prevent="playInstance();"
@click.prevent="playInstance();"
```

I leave it here for future ref.

The prevent does not give the signal of doubleclick and you avoid the zoomin functionalities on mobiles

works great!